# Is there a route component in VueJS similar to React Router?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm adding some breadcrumbs to an existing vueJS app that uses Vue Router. In React, I would've written something like this:

```
<Breadcrumbs>
  <Route path="/users">
    <Breadcrumb>
      <FaUsers />
      Users
    <Breadcrumb>
    <Route path="/users/new">
      <Breadcrumb>
        <FaUserPlus />
        Add
      </Breadcrumb>
    </Route>
  </Route>
</BreadCrumb>
```

This way the crumbs can all be defined on one page in HTML. I'd like to do the same with VueJS, with a breadcrumb component that's inserted into `<router-view name="breadcrumbs" />`:

```
const routes = createRouter({
  routes: [{
    path: "/users",
    components: {
      breadcrumbs: Breadcrumbs,
      default: Users
    },
    children: { ... }
  }, ...]
})
```

But I can't find a Route component that just does route matching in html in Vue. Is there one? Can I avoid creating a tiny vuejs component for each breadcrumb pattern?

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I was fluent in React, but my reading of the [React Router docs on <Route>](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Route) tells me

> The Route component['s] ... most basic responsibility is to render some UI when its path matches the current URL.

Briefly scanning the [Vue Router docs](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/) I don't see an existing component that provides that functionality, but a basic version would be simple to implement with Vue:

```js
<!--Route.vue-->

<template>
  <slot v-if="route.path.includes(props.path)"></slot>
</template>

<script setup>
const props = defineProps({ path: String })
const route = useRoute()
</script>
```

That should fulfill the basic use case of the React version. You can get a lot more complex with it, or not, thus is the beauty of Vue. : )